# How to get user's location from Google Account

Tags: google-plus

How can one get user's location from Google? I can't find any suitable API for that, this is seems rather odd given the many places where Google tracks my location. It doesn't seem to be contained in user's profile, not every Google user uses Google+ so that can't be used either, and no one is actually using Latitude.

http://status-501.tumblr.com/post/19852581283/need-a-location-of-that-google-account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latitude for those that use it, Google+ profile for those that use it and have entered a location, and Android GPS API are the only location APIs that Google publicly provides. You might consider using the [HTML5 Geolocation API](http://html5demos.com/geo).

Answer (score 0):

Now the Google latitude is defunct only Google+ is the viable option.
The location can easily be shared within google+ but I haven't found any solution (yet) to extract it to my application (yet!).